# Limit Windows VPN clients to connecting only to a single IP

Tags: windows, vpn

We are running windows VPN with NPS. Our primary policy grants full network access without much restriction to a security group called VPN Users.

We are hosting an event that will require some guests to access a single Linux VM (or single IP within our range).

My solution would be to create a secondary rule for a temporary Guest VPN securty group and set up IP filters to restrict access to our network.

I've tried setting up IP filtering but am having issues with the IP filter setting, It's not allowing me to filter out our network with the exception of the single IP. I keep getting IP and subnet not compatible whenever I enter the whitelisted IP and our subnet. 
Has anyone gotten this to work using only windows remote access server?

Comment: Do you have anything like a public network zone for this box, in the guest network? Treat it like your public facing services.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I ended up creating an IP filter on a custom grant rule with outbound packet filtering on the network blocks I wanted them to not access added to the rule.